# Select xml node by xpath with attribute value containing apostroph

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, apostrophe

I'm trying to extract some data from a given XML file. Therefore, I have to select some specific nodes by their attribute values. My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg ....>
    ....
    <g font-family="'BentonSans Medium'" font-size="12">
        <text>bla bla bla</text>
        ....
    </g>
    ....
</svg>
```

I've tried to escape the apostrophs in the value but I couldn't get it working.

```
from lxml import etree as ET

tree = ET.parse("file.svg")
root = tree.getroot()

xPath = ".//g[@font-family='&apos;BentonSans Medium&apos;]"
print(root.findall(xPath))
```

I always get errors of this kind:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\lxml\_elementpath.py", line 214, in prepare_predicate
raise SyntaxError("invalid predicate")
```

Anyone got ideas how to select these nodes with XPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
xPath = ".//g[@font-family=\"'BentonSans Medium'\"]"
```

---

Your code fails because you haven't put the closing single quote:

```
xPath = ".//g[@font-family='&apos;BentonSans Medium&apos;]"
```

It should be after the last `&apos;`:

```
xPath = ".//g[@font-family='&apos;BentonSans Medium&apos;']"
```

But it doesn't make the XPath expression correct, as `&apos;` is interpreted just as is.

---

By the way, if you want to check if the `font-family` *contains* the given string, use [`contains()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) XPath function with the `xpath` method:

```
xPath = '//g[contains(@font-family, "BentonSans Medium")]'
print(root.xpath(xPath))
```

*Output*

```
[<Element g at 0x7f2093612108>]
```

The sample code fetches all `g` elements with `font-family` attribute values containing `BentonSans Medium` string.

I don't know why the `findall` method doesn't work with `contains()`, but the `xpath` seems more flexible, and I would recommend using this method instead.

Comment: thank you very much. your small syntax adjustment did it!